# Conjugate and simplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I want to get a cosine from taking the real part of a complex exponential: $cos(x) = Re(exp(i x))$. What I do in *Mathematica* is

```
(1/2)*(Exp[x*I] + Conjugate[Exp[x*I]]) // TraditionalForm // FullSimplify
```

but this gives me `1/2 (E^(-I x^\[Conjugate]) + E^(I x))` instead of `cos(x)`. Why is that?

Comment: `FullSimplify[(Exp[x*I] + Conjugate[Exp[x*I]])/2, x ∈ Reals] // TraditionalForm`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try!

```
(1/2)*(Exp[x*I] + Conjugate[Exp[x*I]])// ComplexExpand
```

> Cos[x]

Also note that `TraditionalForm` is a formatting tool mainly for displaying the formulas in a nice manner. After you have applied `TraditionalForm` on an expression other Mathematica built in functions (e.g `FullSimplify`) may have problem to deal with the expression as an input. Hence better to use `TraditionalForm` only for displaying expressions.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach:

```
Simplify[ExpToTrig @ Re[E^(I x)], x ∈ Reals]
```

> Cos[x]

Answer (score 0):

```
(ExpToTrig@Exp[x*I])[[1]]
```

Cos[x]

```
ComplexExpand[Exp[x*I]] /. I -> 0
```

Cos[x]